# Inserting a node in a linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm going through the implementation of a linked list, which is provided on the following website:

https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/linked-list-c-plus-plus

I'm wondering why they pass the argument `struct Node ** head_ref` in the push function, which is a reference to reference if I am not mistake:

```
void push(struct Node ** head_ref, int new_data) {
    struct Node * new_node = (struct Node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = ( * head_ref);
    ( * head_ref) = new_node;
}
```

They also allocate memory for a new node:

```
struct Node * new_node = (struct Node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Can we replace this line with `Node * new_node = new Node(sizeof(Node))` ?

Comment: If the shown code is recommended on that website, then I suggest finding a better resource. Yes, use `new`, not `malloc`, and you can drop all those `struct`s.

Comment: "Can we replace this ..." - you can replace the whole thing with a `std::list`. But why do you even want a linked list in the first place? It's a horribly performing data structure. In *most* cases, opt for a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `Node * new_node = new Node();` without sizeof...

Comment: I cannot tell if you can because I don't know the definition of `Node` and whether`Node` has a constructor that accepts one `size_t`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yuppers! And you can go a step further with a smarter constructor: `Node(int value, Node * link = nullptr) : data(value), next(link) {}`. Now you can reduce `push` to `* head_ref = new Node(new_data, * head_ref);` Much simpler function.

Comment: @cigien you should take a look at the page if you have the time. It's a laugh riot. Starts off OK, but once it gets into code, it's like an episode of How NOT to do it. Probably should follow Ripley's [immortal advice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q).

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, it's terrible. There's a serious problem on *every* snippet :(